# autofitColumns for range format in excel office js library not working

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js

It seems autofitColumns for range format in excel api 1.1 of the office js is not working properly or I am not using it properly

code example:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    sheet.getRange("A1:B2").format.autofitColumns();
    return ctx.sync();
})
.catch(function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
         console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    });
```

The error object is as follows.

```
Error: {"description":"Object doesn't support property or method 'autofitColumns'","number":-2146827850,"stack":"TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'autofitColumns'\n   at ....
```

I tried also to load "format" and/or "format/*" first then sync but didn't work either

I am running against Excel 2016 windows 64 bit edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autofitting was only added in ExcelApi 1.2 (which you can see in the intellisense comments for that method).  So if I had to guess, I wonder if you're on the RTM/MSI version of Office 2016.  If you do a runtime check for requirement sets, do you get that `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', 1.1)` return true, but the same call with `1.2` returns false?

Comment: Thanks alot, I think that was it, I update the office and now it work, I guess i will just have to add the check before calling autofitcolumns.